# Can't create sqlite tables with foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to do a simple example of using a foreign key to link two tables via sqlite. However, I keep getting errors.

I have two tables. Member, Character. A member can have multiple characters.

Here is the schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "member" (
    "member_id" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "platform_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "index" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE "character" (
    "character_id"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "index" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "member_index"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (member_index)
       REFERENCES member (index)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

```
Result: near "index": syntax error
At line 6:
CREATE TABLE "character" (
    "character_id"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "index" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "member_index"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (member_index)
       REFERENCES member (index
```

If I remove the Foreign Key part, then it works, but of course, then I dont have the foreign key.

This seems about as simple of an example that there can be, but I cannot get it to work. Any suggestions on what I am missing?

Comment: If you are just using plain SQLite then you must visit this link [https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-foreign-key/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary key is simply called `index`:

```
CREATE TABLE "character" (
    "character_id"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "index" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "member_index"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (member_index)
       REFERENCES member ("index");
```

`index` however, is a really bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.  As a habit, I also make primary keys the first column in a table.  I would change the name and recommend:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    member_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    member_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    platform_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE characters (
    character_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    character_name  TEXT NOT NULL,
    member_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES members(member_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Note the changes:

- No escaping of the column names.  These are not needed and the double quotes just clutter the code.
- The "id"s are all numeric.  There is no requirement, but this is rather typical usage of the term.
- What were the "id"s are now called "name"s.
- The table names are in the plural.  This is a convention that I use because the tables represent a set of entities, not just one.
- `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` are redundant when used with `PRIMARY KEY`.  No need for them.
- SQLite requires `INTEGER` to be fully spelled out for primary keys.
- The changes in names mean that the primary key and foreign key have the same names.

Answer (score 0):

`index` is a poor choice for a column name. That's a [SQLite keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), so it needs to be quoted everywhere it is used - the foreign key declaration does not:

```
CREATE TABLE "character" (
    "character_id"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "index" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "member_index"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (member_index)
       REFERENCES member ("index") --> here
       ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I would warmly recommend choosing a different name - that does not conflict with a keyword - so you don't need to permanently remember not to forget the quotes. There are plenty of words in English, and only 145 SQLite keywords.